# I am New in Hibernate and Make simple application Like insert Data in a database

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, servlets

this My Login.hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Login1" table="Login1">
    <id name="id" column="LID" type="integer">
      <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="email" column="EMAIL" type="string"></property>
    <property name="password" column="PASS" type="string"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Could not get constructor for
>    org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

This is my class file:

```
   public class Login1 implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private String date;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

My Login1 has more property but i want add only email and password

Comment: Looks like problem with get or set methods of the Login class.Can you post your Login class here?

Comment: Why you have spaces in your class and method names? --> `class LOGIN 1` , `get Amount` , `get Name`. I think you have to learn Java before learning Hibernate

Comment: @Chaitanya that is corrected now.

Comment: @John, post the complete stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

please check your constructor,set and get methods of your login class.Check if there are some mis spelling or if they are missing
 refer https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2453286